# TypeError: 'Connection' object is not subscriptable

Tags: flask, subscription

This is the end of the error output in terminal:

```
File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/evahub/backend/rest_delete.py", line 23, in deleteDocument
    user = getDbUser(username)
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/evahub/backend/db_users_broker.py", line 25, in getDbUser
    usersCollection = db["users"]
TypeError: 'Connection' object is not subscriptable
```

I did some refactoring and all of a sudden, this piece of code is not working any more. So I have rest_delete.py file:

```
...
user = getDbUser(username)
...
```

which calls this method from file db_users_broker.py:

```
from db_config import getDb

db = getDb()
def getDbUser(username):
    usersCollection = db["users"]
    uq = {"username": username}

    user = usersCollection.find_one(uq)
    if user == None:
        return None
    else:
        return user
```

which in turn calls this code from the third file:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_DB"] = "evahub"
app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST"] = "localhost"


def getDb():
    mysql = MySQL(
        app,
        prefix="",
        host=app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST"],
        user=app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_USER"],
        password=app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD"],
        db=app.config["MYSQL_DATABASE_DB"],
        autocommit=True,
    )
    connection = mysql.connect()
    return connection
```

where is the error here, I am not subscripting to anything, what is this about, how to resolve it?

Comment: Your function `getDb` just sets up your database connection. Nothing in the code appears to query your database to retrieve your user collection. My guess is your refactoring removed something similar to `db.query(Users).all()`

Comment: dude you are right! We switched from mongo to mysql, and that is a remnant of mongo. I need to refactor all code that has that db[colection name] in it. Thanks.